# How to avoid exponent while converting a string to number in DataWeave 1.0

Tags: java, mule, dataweave

I am converting a string "0.0000000" stored in payload say Amount to number in Data Weave language 1.0

I tried **payload.Amount as :number**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
 Amount: payload.Amount as :number when payload.Amount != null
}
```

I am expecting final output as **0.0000000** but i am getting **0E-7**

Comment: The number of zeros after decimal point is not fixed to 7, it may vary from zero times to more than 10 times. e.g. 0.0, 0, 0.00, 0.000000000000

Comment: Can you give more details on your requirements ? like from where the data is coming and where it needs to go. Do you just need the correct format for printing or some other system needs to consume it ?

Answer (score 3):

I think your expectation is incorrect. 0E-7 is a perfectly valid number for JSON according to [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). Any correct parser should handle this valid number correctly. As in other languages, numbers don't have a formatting property in JSON. Only when they are converted to/from strings a format can be applied. For these reasons you can not tell DataWeave to use a particular formatting.

Now, if you have a particular issue that makes 0E-7 a problem, please update the description to add more details of that.

One alternative that might work if setting a fixed number of decimals is OK, is to adapt the method described at https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-force-DataWeave-to-return-Long-number

Example

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function withZeroes(x)  x as :string { format: "#.####" } as :number
---
{
  Amount: withZeroes(0E-7),
  Amount2: withZeroes(0.000),
  Amount3: withZeroes(0.0001),
  Amount4: withZeroes(0.00001)
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Amount": 0,
  "Amount2": 0,
  "Amount3": 0.0001,
  "Amount4": 0
}
```

Comment: I agree this is a perfectly valid number and it should be acceptable by any system. This number, 0E-7 is getting consumed by other service on PCF(Pivotal Cloud Foundry) and it is throwing error there as **Invalid number exception**.

Comment: That is a problem of the parser used by that service. It doesn't handle that border case well. There is a possible solution if you don't need to preserve the zeros at the right end of the decimal point. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to specify precision. Something like

as :number as :string {format: "0.0000000"}

More samples discussed here

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-format-numbers-in-DataWeave

Comment: I tried this one and its giving **"0.0000000"** in quotes but i need final output as number not as string, without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try like

as :number as :number {format: "#.#######"}